# Como guardar dados de varias consultas MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela com dados de diversos metais e preciso pegar esses dados para usar em minha página, mas não estou conseguindo pegar todos, apenas o primeiro funciona.

**Código:**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "metais");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM historical_data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2");

    $cobre = "[";
    while($array_cobre = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $d1 = explode("-", $array_cobre['data']);
        $cobre .= "{x: new Date(".$d1['0'].", ".($d1['1'] - 1).", ".$d1['2']."), y: ".$array_cobre['copper']."},";
    }
    echo $cobre .= "]";

    $aluminio = "[";
    while($array_aluminio = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $d1 = explode("-", $array_aluminio['data']);
        $aluminio .= "{x: new Date(".$d1['0'].", ".($d1['1'] - 1).", ".$d1['2']."), y: ".$array_aluminio['aluminium']."},";
    }
    echo $aluminio .= "]";

    $chumbo = "[";
    while($array_chumbo = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $d1 = explode("-", $array_chumbo['data']);
        $chumbo .= "{x: new Date(".$d1['0'].", ".($d1['1'] - 1).", ".$d1['2']."), y: ".$array_chumbo['lead']."},";
    }
    echo $chumbo .= "]";
```

**Saída:**

```
[{x: new Date(2016, 2, 25), y: 493100},{x: new Date(2016, 2, 24), y: 493100},]
[]
[]
```

**Novo código (Array):**

```
$itens = []; 
while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $d1 = explode("-", $array['data']); 
    $itens['cobre'][] = sprintf("{x: new Date(%s, %s, %s), y: %s}", $d1[0], $d1[1]-1, $d1[2], $array['copper']);
    $itens['aluminio'][] = sprintf("{x: new Date(%s, %s, %s), y: %s}", $d1[0], $d1[1], $d1[2], $array['aluminium']);
    $itens['chumbo'][] = sprintf("{x: new Date(%s, %s, %s), y: %s}", $d1[0], $d1[1]-1, $d1[2], $array['lead']);
} 
echo json_encode($itens);
```

**Nova saída (Array):**

```
{
"cobre":["{x: new Date(2016, 2, 25), y: 493100}","{x: new Date(2016, 2, 24), y: 493100}"],
"aluminio":["{x: new Date(2016, 03, 25), y: 146950}","{x: new Date(2016, 03, 24), y: 146950}"],
"chumbo":["{x: new Date(2016, 2, 25), y: 175500}","{x: new Date(2016, 2, 24), y: 175500}"]
}
```

Como faço pra pegar cada metal separadamente e jogar na variável que vou usar?

```
echo json_encode($itens['cobre']);
echo json_encode($itens['aluminio']);
echo json_encode($itens['chumbo']);
```

Comment: vc está monta um json com isso? pq não usa json_encode?

Comment: pq não sei usar msm @rray, teria como me ajudar com isso? Fui fazendo da forma q sabia.

Comment: Essas 3 consultas são encadeadas ou separadas?

Comment: elas são separadas, eu preciso fzr 3 json diferentes e independentes uma do outro, usando a query $result. Cada json pega a info de uma metal diferente na tabela

Comment: Eu não entendi vc roda 3 vezes a mesma cosulta para pegar a mesma informação? em todas é usando `$result` no `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: veja se funciona : `$itens = [];
 while($array_cobre = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $d1 = explode("-", $array_cobre['data']);
  $itens['coper']['x'][] = sprintf("new Date(%s, %s, %s)", $d1[0], $d1[1]-1, $d1[2]);
  $itens['coper']['y'][] = $array_aluminio['copper'];
  
  $itens['aluminium']['x'][] = sprintf("new Date(%s, %s, %s)", $d1[0], $d1[1]-1, $d1[2]);
  $itens['aluminium']['y'][] = $array_aluminio['aluminium'];
  
  $itens['lead']['x'][] = sprintf("new Date(%s, %s, %s)", $d1[0], $d1[1]-1, $d1[2]);
  $itens['lead']['y'][] = $array_aluminio['lead'];
 }
 
 echo json_encode($itens);`

Comment: a principio não @rray, mas com alguns ajustes funcionou sim, vou editar a pergunta com a nova saída, me ajuda a separar por favor

Comment: Usar, `echo $itens['cobre']['x']` ou `echo $itens['chumbo']['x']` não resolve? o que está faltando? ou a formatação dos dados ficou errada?

Comment: então, eu estou usando isso em uma função jquery (canvasjs), e cada material tem que ficar exatamente assim:  {x: new Date(2016, 03, 24), y: 493100}, {x: new Date(2016, 03, 25), y: 493100}, ...

Comment: Mudei o código, acredito que agora o resultado está certo, basicamente mudou a atribuição do array e a crição de um indice(`$i`) para juntar o x e o y, veja [nesse link](http://ideone.com/YgIBVy)

Comment: não entendi muito bem @rray, mas fiz uma alteração no seu primeiro codigo que funcionou:  $itens = []; 
 while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $d1 = explode("-", $array['data']); 
  $itens['cobre'][] = sprintf("{x: new Date(%s, %s, %s), y: %s}", $d1[0], $d1[1]-1, $d1[2], $array['copper']);
  $itens['aluminio'][] = sprintf("{x: new Date(%s, %s, %s), y: %s}", $d1[0], $d1[1], $d1[2], $array['aluminium']);
  $itens['chumbo'][] = sprintf("{x: new Date(%s, %s, %s), y: %s}", $d1[0], $d1[1]-1, $d1[2], $array['lead']);
 } 
 echo json_encode($itens);

Comment: Esse código ai ficou mais simples, basicamente vc já manda a string formatada.

Comment: foi na base ta intuição kk vlw msm! pega o codigo novo que eu coloquei na pergunta e deixa como resposta aki pra eu marcar @rray

Comment: Raylan reponde vc mesmo :) quem teve a sacada de como simplificar foi vc. Olha o meu código do ideone hahaha não ficou mto legal. Depois de um tempo vc pode aceitar sua resposta.

Comment: ah blz então, mas vlw msm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido!

**Código:**

```
$itens = []; 
while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $d1 = explode("-", $array['data']); 
    $itens['cobre'][] = sprintf("{x: new Date(%s, %s, %s), y: %s}", $d1[0], $d1[1]-1, $d1[2], $array['copper']);
    $itens['aluminio'][] = sprintf("{x: new Date(%s, %s, %s), y: %s}", $d1[0], $d1[1], $d1[2], $array['aluminium']);
    $itens['chumbo'][] = sprintf("{x: new Date(%s, %s, %s), y: %s}", $d1[0], $d1[1]-1, $d1[2], $array['lead']);
} 
echo json_encode($itens);
```

**Saída:**

```
{
"cobre":["{x: new Date(2016, 2, 25), y: 493100}","{x: new Date(2016, 2, 24), y: 493100}"],
"aluminio":["{x: new Date(2016, 03, 25), y: 146950}","{x: new Date(2016, 03, 24), y: 146950}"],
"chumbo":["{x: new Date(2016, 2, 25), y: 175500}","{x: new Date(2016, 2, 24), y: 175500}"]
}
```

**Metais separados:**

```
echo json_encode($itens['cobre']);
echo json_encode($itens['aluminio']);
echo json_encode($itens['chumbo']);
```